# Dependency error when using aar library

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, aar

I have a module with a .aar file in libs folder. I used the solution posted here 
  [1]: http://kevinpelgrims.com/blog/2014/05/18/reference-a-local-aar-in-your-android-project/  to add the .aar file as dependency and was able to compile the module properly.

Now I want to use this module as a dependency to the main module in my project and compile. However when i try to compile, i do see an error which says that ***gradle was not able to find the particular .aar file***. why would my main module not find a file which is in the libs folder of my sub module. Was wondering if anyone came across this issue.

my project structure is like this

```
--mainmodule
  --build.gradle (submodule as a dependency)
--submodule
   --libs
      -- abc.aar
```

Here is the error gradle throws: `When unzipping library ':abc:, either group, name or version is empty`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If I understand your problem right and you've followed the steps described in the link you shared, then adding this to your **mainmodule's build.gradle** should do the job:

```
flatDir {
    dirs "../submodule/libs"
}
```

You basically have the same issue that you fixed in your `submodule`, since the `mainmodule` is struggling to resolve transitive dependencies (abc.aar) of `submodule`.

**Recommended way:**

While the answer above should fix your issue, Android Studio supports a better way to do this. Import a local aar file via the **File>New>New Module>Import .JAR/.AAR Package** option in Android Studio v1.3+.
You can then have your submodule depend on that `aar-module` as follows:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':aar-module')
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. Apparently, thats the right way to do it.